# Error handling on quarkus mutiny rest client

Tags: quarkus, mutiny

On my quarkus rest project i have a restclient that uses mutiny:

```
@Path("/")
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "my-api")
@RegisterClientHeaders
@RegisterProvider(MyExceptionMapper.class)
public interface MyClient {

  @POST
  @Path("path")
  Uni<MyBean> get(String body);
}
```

I wanna handle propery non 2XX httpError so i have made my ExceptionMaper

```
public class MyExceptionMapper implements ResponseExceptionMapper<MyException> {
  @Override
  public MyException toThrowable(Response response) {
    //TODO
    return new MyException();
  }
}
```

a bad call on the client shows that MyExceptionMapper handle the response but the exception raises and does not became a failure on my Uni Client response object

```
Uni<MyBean> bean = myClient.get("") // i do not have a failure in case of 4XX http 
   .onFailure().invoke(fail -> System.out.println("how can i get here?"));
```

Am i using mutiny on a rest client in the wrong way?

Thanks

UPDATE

ok i forgot to add the dependency quarkus-rest-client-mutiny, adding this i notice 2 things,

- i still pass through Myexceptionmapper
- i also produce a Uni.failure, but the exception into the failure is not the custom exception i created into MyExceptionmapper but a RestEasyWebApplicationException

  *Failure : org.jboss.resteasy.client.exception.ResteasyWebApplicationException: Unknown error, status code 400
  at org.jboss.resteasy.client.exception.WebApplicationExceptionWrapper.wrap(WebApplicationExceptionWrapper.java:107)
  at org.jboss.resteasy.microprofile.client.DefaultResponseExceptionMapper.toThrowable(DefaultResponseExceptionMapper.java:21)*

Does the ExceptionMapper becomes useless in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a bug in `quarkus-rest-client-mutiny`. I created an [Github issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/21175) based on your findings.

It will work as you expect if you switch to `quarkus-rest-client-reactive`

Comment: but with quarkus-rest-client reactive i loose the Uni interface and have to switch to CompletionStage?

Comment: Nope, `Uni` works perfectly fine. The classic `quarkus-rest-client` needs `quarkus-rest-client-mutiny` to support `Uni`. `quarkus-rest-client-reactive` does not.

Comment: ok i forgot to add the dependency quarkus-rest-client-mutiny, adding this i notice 2 things, i still pass through Myexceptionmapper and produce a failure, but the exception into the failure is not the custom exception i created into MyExceptionmapper but a RestEasyWebApplicationException

Comment: If you use `quarkus-rest-client-reactive`, you do not need to add any extra dependency to get `Uni` support. It's built-in.